# Can the Android Device Manager API Force the User to Create a PIN?

Tags: android, security

I want an app to only be able to run if the user is using a screen lock password.  As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a good way to force a user to use a PIN on their device.

Comment: what you can do is redirecting the user to the screen lock settings when there is no screen lock. That is what the VPN settings activity does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to force the user to use pin on their device.

The only thing you need is administrator privileges (no root required).
you can read about it here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

with code example, etc..